# Migrate Data from one Riak cluster to another

Tags: data-migration, riak, riak-kv

I have a situation where we need to migrate data from one Riak cluster to another and then remove the old cluster. The ring size will be same, even the region will be the same. We need to do this to upgrade the instances to AL2. Is there a clean approach to do so on Prod, without realtime data loss?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this may be tied to your version of Riak KV. If you have the open source version of Riak KV 2.2.3 or earlier, this will require an in-situ upgrade to Riak KV 2.2.6 before progressing. See https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.2.6/setup/upgrading/version/ with packages at https://files.tiot.jp/riak/kv/2.2/2.2.6/

For an Enterprise Editions of Riak KV 2.2.3 and earlier or the open source edition of Riak KV 2.2.6 or higher, you can use multi-data centre replication (MDC).

Use both of these at the same time for proper replication and to prevent data loss:

- fullsync replication will copy across all stored data on its first run and then any missing data on subsequent runs.
- realtime replication will replicate all transactions in almost realtime.

If you then set this up as bidirectional replication (get each cluster to replicate to the other for both fullsync and realtime) then you will be able to seemlessly switch your production environment from one cluster to the other without any issues. Once you are happy everything is working as expected, you can kill the old cluster.

Please see the documentation for replication at https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.2.6/using/cluster-operations/v3-multi-datacenter/